# X Position by Generation in Dendrogram

Tags: javascript, layout, svg, d3.js, dendrogram

I am using the standard dendrogram layout in D3:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html

But I would like the child nodes to be fixed to the position of their "generation", so for instance, vis.visualization would appear at the same X coordinate as vis.operator and, similarly, operator.IOperator would appear directly beneath operator.Label.

The Node-Link Tree does it this way, so maybe I'll find the answer there:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/tree.html

Right, there's a layout that does just this...
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html